# Total number of combinations for boxes that can hold a maximum of 2 objects.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Consider an $N$ balls than can be placed in $n$ number of boxes.

Where: $n > N/2$

Suppose each boxes can only hold a maximum of two balls, what is the formula for finding the total number of combinations if each balls are considered distinguishable?

Comment: The boxes are too distinguishable?

Comment: @ArukaJ I dont think that what you says is right because if you multiply by $n!$ you are permutating the balls inside each box (if they are two). It seems that the balls inside a box are just a combination, so order doesnt matter.

Comment: Removed my comments, posted in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be reformulated: Find the number of partitions of a N-set into n parts each containing at most two elements.$$\sum_{i=N-n}^{N/2}\frac{N!}{i!2^i(N-2i)!}$$
Example 1:
For $N=4,n=2$ from last formula we get $$\frac{4!}{2!2^20!}=3$$ the partitions are
$$(ab|cd),(ac|bd),(ad|bc)$$
Example 2:
For $N=3,n=2$ from last formula we get $$\frac{3!}{1!2^11!}=3$$ the partitions are
$$(ab|c),(ac|b),(a|bc)$$
Example 3:
For $N=4,n=3$ from last formula we get $$\frac{4!}{1!2^12!}=6$$ the partitions are
$$(\emptyset|ab|cd),(\emptyset|ac,bd),(\emptyset|ad|bc)$$
$$(a|b|cd),(a|c|bd),(a|d|bc)$$

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate a little to make this answer more useful.

Comment: While correct, I'm not sure this answer is very useful, especially with no explanation.

Comment: Yes explanation would be useful

Comment: The $2$'s there are the max number of balls in each box? So if its 5 then all 2's will be replaced by 5?

Comment: Hi, what if instead of 2, each box can hold a total number of $m$ balls?

Answer (score 3):

Since the boxes are indistinguishable we have to count the number of ways we can pair off **some** of $n\geq1$ distinguishable people $P_k$, $1\leq k\leq n$. Denote this number by $a_n$. Then $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and we have the following recursion:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+ n\>a_{n-1}\ .$$
The reason is as follows: You can decide to keep person $P_{n+1}$ alone and pair off the remaining $n$ persons at leisure, or you can pair $P_{n+1}$ off with a chosen person $P_k$, $1\leq k\leq n$, and then pair off the remaining $n-1$ persons at leisure.

The resulting sequence is
$$1, 2, 4, 10, 26, 76, 232, 764, 2620, 9496, 35696, 140152, 568504, \ldots\ ,$$
which is [A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085) at OEIS.

Comment: Hi, what if each box can either hold $0$ to $m$ balls?